# Days to Next Thursday

Tags: c

I m trying to write a code in C on caclulating days until next thursday. I need help, using this paragrah.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule#Finding_the_day_of_the_week_of_a_given_calendar_date

any ideas on how i should apporach it, and rough guideline

Comment: btw it needs to be kept in simple C language, nothing too technical

Comment: link is what i m trying to achieve, but i am stuck for ideas, any pointers?

Comment: I take it `localtime` and `localtime_r` are "too technical", i.e. you want to do it all for yourself, So, is the problem that you don't understand the Wikipedia article, or that you don't know how to write C code, or a bit of both? It's hard to give pointers when we don't know what you're missing.

Comment: i understand wiki article, and i know bits of C, and yes localtime are too technical. I needs pointers on the C how to proceed with this.

Comment: To start, then, the modulus operator in C is `%`, and integer division of positive numbers rounds down, which is what you want when "floor" occurs in the article's equations. You'll want to use a combination of calculations, with lookup-tables (arrays) containing things like the memorable Doomsdays in each month or the anchor days for the centuries.

Answer (score 2):

Separate your problem in smaller problems.

When you feel like a smaller problem is small enough to solve, solve that problem.

For instance: your master problem is *"using the technique described in the wikipedia article calculate how many days are there till next Thursday"*.

Problems small enough to make into a function:

- calculate (or lookup) a year's doomsday (Monday for 2011) *`yeardoomsday(2011)`*
- calculate (or lookup) a month doomsday (7 for March) *`monthdoomsday(2011, 3)`*
  <sup>calls yeardoomsday(2011) somewhere inside the function</sup>
- ...